# How can I find the position of a character in a string? [Python]

Tags: python, loops

I have this String: **"----d---"**

How can I find the position of the "d" in Python?

I want this ouput:

```
Position: 5
```

Comment: ```print("----d---".index("d")+1)```, plus one since python's index starts from 0

Answer (score 1):

### Improved answer:

```
def get_position(s: str, c: str):
    return s.index(c)

print("Position:", get_position("----d---", "d"))
```

### Previous, more basic answer:

```
def get_position(s: str, c: str):
    for i, char in enumerate(s):
        if char == c:
            return i


print("Position:", get_position(s="----d---", c="d"))
```

Comment: I like this approach. Only change I would make is to create a function with the Improved Answer:
```def find_index(s, c):
    return("Position:", s.index(c)+1)```

Comment: Worked your suggestion into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Use rindex:

```
jeff = "wow bru"
print("Position:",jeff.rindex("r")+1)
```

### Explanation:

`jeff.rindex("r")` returns the index of the letter r in the string assigned to `jeff`, and `+1` just increaces that value by one, because indexing starts with 0 and we want it to start with 1.